# Prototype believes JSON from PHP is string

Tags: javascript, json, loops, prototypejs

I have the following code in JS:

```
    new Ajax.Request('http://www.some_random_url.com',
      {
        parameters: { start : this.start, stop : this.stop },
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: function(transport){

          var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
          alert("Success! \n\n" + response.posts);
          $(response.posts).each( function(item) {
            alert(item.title);
            }
        },
        onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
      });
```

and then I have the following code in PHP. The function takes an array as an argument, and is meant to output JSON.

```
function view_api($array) {

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$array));

}
```

Still, it seems to be treated by prototypejs as a string. When `response` is alerted, everything is fine. But the each loop in JS says `response.posts` is undefined.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's returning the JSON as a string then you should parse it first.

```
var data = JSON.parse(payload);
```

Comment: JSON.parse may break if the browser doesn't have native JSON support and they are not using a library to add it. evalJSON will work regardless of browser as it's part of the prototype API we know Helge has.

Answer (score 2):

use evalJSON() to typecast the response in JSON object as

```
var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON() || "no response text";
```

Answer (score 1):

set `evalJSON: 'force'` in the prototype ajax request options. then use `var response = transport.responseJSON`

Comment: i should add that this method will fall back to prototypes `evalJSON` method if the browser doesn't support `JSON.parse`. now that's #winning

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick with prototype.js is that you can pass the following headers and it will automatically be converted to json.

```
header('X-JSON: (' . json_encode($data) . ')');
header('Content-type: application/x-json');
```